# Filtering returned LDAP attributes by value

Tags: ldap

**Context**

There a a few occasions when I wish I could filter the list of attributes in a search request not only by attribute *names* (e.g: only return `mail, cn, memberOf` for a user, or `defaultNamingContext, supportedControl` from a rootDSE query)

but also by attribute *values*, e.g :

- instead of receiving 100+ `memberOf` items, only return `memberOf` lines that match `CN=Users,OU=Groups,DC=foo,DC=com` or `CN=HR,OU=Groups,DC=foo,DC=com` or `CN=Admin,OU=Groups,DC=foo,DC=com`
- instead of receiving all supportedControls, only check for `1.2.840.113556.1.4.319` and `1.2.840.113556.1.4.841`

**Question**

Is there a way, in a search request, to filter the list of returned attributes based on their *value* ?

perhaps with an extra search control ?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to filter which values are returned from a multi-value attribute.

However, there still might be a way to optimize what you're trying to do.

If you got your results from searching for users, then you can include those criteria in your search filter. For example, to only return users that are members of any of those three groups, you can add this in your filter:

```
(|(memberOf=CN=Users,OU=Groups,DC=foo,DC=com)(memberOf=CN=HR,OU=Groups,DC=foo,DC=com)(memberOf=CN=Admin,OU=Groups,DC=foo,DC=com))
```

For `supportedControl` on the `RootDSE`,  you don't have any other option. You can't even do a search on `RootDSE`. I tried: no matter what filter you give it, it always returns the `RootDSE` entry, even if the filter doesn't match.

But looping through the values of an attribute isn't an expensive operation. When it comes to efficiency, the most expensive operations are the network requests to the DC. When you get the values of an attribute, you usually get *all* the data in one request. Looping through the `memberOf` or `supportedControl` values is done entirely in memory and is super quick.

The only time you have to go back to the server to get more values of a multi-value attribute is if there are more than 1500 values (for Active Directory anyway). That will usually only happen when you're looking at the members of a large group. More on that here: [Range Retrieval of Attribute Values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-adts/e27b48db-6f82-44cd-9038-2e54f790cc1f)

Comment: It's not entirely true that there's no way to only retrieve matching values but the client and server have to use/support the [matched values control](https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/Matched%20Values%20Control) (see [RFC 3876](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3876)).

Comment: @MichaelStröder You learn something every day. I only have experience with Active Directory and that control doesn't seem to be supported by AD, so that's probably why I never knew this.